# Capistrano: organizing folders for different environments

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I'm approaching to Capistrano and I want to understand better how I have to organize the folder structure on the server.

Let's suppose I have two branch:

- `master`
- `develop`

That are visible respectively on:

- `www.example.org`
- `develop.example.org`

Actually (no-Capistrano), on the server I have:

- `/home/sites/example.org/www`
- `/home/sites/example.org/develop`

But, with Capistrano, I will have only `/home/sites/example.org/current`.

How can I manage the "production/development" situation with Capistrano?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can override the deployment folder in your environment config. For example, you have the default deployment location in `config/deploy.rb` using `set :deploy_to, '/home/sites/example.org/www'`. Then you set up `config/develop.rb` and `config/production.rb` (these names are arbitrary and don't need to map to the branch names):

```
server 'servername', user: 'username', roles: %w(app db web)
set :deploy_to, '/home/sites/example.org/develop'
```

In general, anything you set in `deploy.rb` can be overridden in `deploy/[env].rb`.

Comment: I hoped there was a better solution, like something that create different folders in the same project (for example, `current` for production, `develop` for `development` and `staging` for staging)

Comment: Ah. I see. It may be theoretically possible to point each env at the same folder and then have a custom symlink task which uses a special variable to select the name of the symlink. However, you'd also have to handle rollback and a ton of other edge cases. At the end of the day, I'd just deploy into different folders. If you need all of the endpoints in the same folder, create a folder with symlinks pointing at the current symlinks for each project.